# Kubernetes HA data across several workers

Tags: kubernetes, vps

I have set up a Kubernetes system with 1 Master and 3 worker Nodes, and a load balancer. But at the moment my pipes are stuck as I'm struggling to find a solution, how can I setup a WordPress website with traffic that is replicated on all nodes. All for me is clear only I don't get, how to get all 3 Workers ( VPS servers in different countries) to have the same data so that pods can work and scale, and if one worker is dead the second and third can continue providing all services. IS PVE the solution or some other? Please point me in the direction to start searching.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `PersistentVolumeClaim` in `ReadWriteMany` mode that creates a `PersistentVolume` that holds your WordPress site data then create a `Deployment` with 3 replicas that mounts that `PersistentVolume`.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: wordpress-data
spec:
  accessModes: 
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  storageClass: fast # update this to whatever persistent storage class is available on your cluster.  See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wordpress
        image: wordpress:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/var/www/html"
            name: wordpress-data
      volumes:
        - name: wordpress-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: wordpress-data # notice this is referencing the PersistentVolumeClaim we declared above
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress
spec:
  type: NodePort # or LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: wordpress
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```